# php/mysql add rows together to get total

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, row, addition

here's the scenario. I am generating a report of all the members who have dues to pay for a certain time period.

I am successfully selecting and displaying each database entry as a row in a html table.

The problem is the total fields the report must have. Each member pays different amounts based on what services they use, so I must add the values in each field individually to ensure proper result.

Question is, how do I go about adding the rows/field together?

Edit:

To clarify. I am adding dues paid and donations paid fields. They are classified and integer in mysql database.

Example, let's say that my query returns 3 results. I wish to add the dues paid for all 3 results and display it as total_dues_paid. Same idea for donations.

This must be dynamic for any given number of results, as this changes month to month and we have seen several hundred results in some months.

Thanks

Comment: You need to give a bit more info about your table structure, and what exactly you're trying to add together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add fields (columns):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, (col1+col2+col3) AS Total FROM table;
```

To add rows together, use the `SUM()` aggregate:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  SUM(col1) AS col1_total,
  SUM(col2) AS col2_total
FROM table
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: any way I can make this automatically adjust for as many rows as there might be?

Comment: @JonYork Using `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions already adjusts for whatever number of rows are selected according to your `WHERE` clause.  I didn't include a `WHERE` in my example though.  By this example, if user1 had 14 rows and user2 had 3 rows, your result would be 2 rows: 1 for each user as the sum of 14 rows for user1 and all 3 rows for user2.

Comment: Everything seems to work, except, how do I get my view to display that variable?

Comment: @JohnYork If you have aliased the column with the `AS` keyword, then you use that alias. Ex: `SELECT SUM(col1) AS col1_total`  Then if you've gotten the result from mysql in PHP, access it as `$row['col1_total']` or whatever your result set array is.  It's the same as accessing a regular column.

Comment: for enough, however, my result is displaying "Array" instead of the summation.

Comment: I figured out my mistakes! that you very much for the help.

For anyone else reading this, please see this topic

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338256/codeigniter-select-sum-returns-array-not-numerical-value

Answer (score 2):

You can add in your query string.

```
SELECT (field1 + field2) AS Total
FROM table
```